# definedness constraint on parametrized roles

Tags: raku, parameterized-types

Should it be possible to add a definedness constraint on parameterized roles?  The following attempt:

```
role R[::T] { }
class C {
    method m ( R[Str]:D $a ) { }
}
```

results in:

> Invalid typename 'D' in parameter declaration.
> at ... scratch.raku:4
> ------>         method m ( R[Str]:D⏏ $a ) { }

and declaring a variable:

```
role R[::T] { }
class S does R[Str] { }
my R[Str]:D $r = S.new;
```

results in:

> Malformed my
> at ... scratch.raku:8
> ------> my R[Str]⏏:D $r = S.new;

Comment: Do you want `R:D[Str]` ?

Comment: It looks like yes.  Would you like to post as an answer?

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR** @wamba's answer assumes the "definiteness" interpretation of your question (which seems likely to be what you actually meant) and provides a nice succinct solution for that. This answer explains why your question is ambiguous, and provides a solution for both interpretations. Neither of my solutions are @wamba's, so this answer serves as a complement to theirs.

## Your question is ambiguous

Here's what you wrote at the start:

> Should it be possible to add a *definedness* constraint on parameterized roles?

Here instead is the implicit question:

> Should it be possible to add a **definiteness** constraint on parameterized roles?

I'll address them in reverse order, given that it's near certain you meant *definite*, not *defined*.

## Definite

Definiteness corresponds to the `:D` type constraint or `.DEFINITE` compiler macro.

This is what the code in your question is about.

The fact that `R[Str]:D` is invalid syntax may be due to an oversight, or lack of tuits, or lack of consensus, or a deliberate decision. I have not researched that. Someone may have filed an issue about it.¹ Again, I have not researched that.

Here's a way to add an equivalent *definiteness* constraint that works for your example:

```
role R[::T] { }
class C {
    method m ( R[Str] $a where .DEFINITE) { 42 }
}

say C.new.m: R[Str].new; # 42
say C.new.m: R[Str];     # Constraint type check failed in binding to parameter '$a'
```

## Defined

Definedness corresponds to the `.defined` method call, as tested by features such as `with` and infix `//`.

This is what your question's title and opening sentence refer to, taken literally.

> Should it be possible to add a *definedness* constraint on parameterized roles?

Here's one way:

```
role R[::T] { }
class C {
    method m ( R[Str] $a where .defined) { 42 }
}

say C.new.m: R[Str].new; # 42
say C.new.m: R[Str];     # Constraint type check failed in binding to parameter '$a'
```

---

Note how the result is the same as for `.DEFINITE` (and would have been if `Type[Type]:D` was valid syntax).

But they aren't *always* the same for *all* objects, which reflects the fact that a definiteness constraint is not exactly the same as a definedness constraint -- `:D` and `.DEFINITE` correspond to *definiteness* whereas `.defined` corresponds to *definedness*.

## Definite vs Defined

The similarity between definiteness and definedness is deliberate. If a given object has not got a `.defined` method (and almost none do) it will inherit `Mu`'s. And that `.defined` method just returns `self.DEFINITE`.

But while the `DEFINITE` method cannot be overridden², the `.defined` one can be:

1. *Users* may override `.defined` for their classes/objects. This makes it easy for someone writing a foreign language adaptor to allow Raku interop with another PL which has a different notion of definedness than Raku's. (This is pretty much the only use case. It is generally ill-advised for ordinary Raku code to override `.defined`.)
2. The built in `Failure` class overrides `.defined`. It returns *`False`* for *both* the type object (as normal) *and instances*. Thus:

```
say "{.DEFINITE.gist}\t{.defined.gist}\t{.gist}"
  for (Mu, Mu.new, Int, 42, Failure, Failure.new)
```

displays:

```
False False   (Mu)
True  True    Mu.new
False False   (Int)
True  True    42
False False   (Failure)
True  False   (HANDLED) Failed
```

The last line, which corresponds to `Failure.new`, has `True` in the first column (its `.DEFINITE` is `True`) but `False` in the *second* column (its `.defined` is `False`).

## Footnotes

¹ I don't think an issue should be filed for making `Type[Type]:D` work. Similarly, if an issue has been filed, then I would anticipate it being ignored for the foreseeable future unless a non-core-dev creates a suitable PR for it (which may still be rejected).

² Definiteness is fundamental to the static typing foundation of Raku's gradual type system *and* its notion that an "object" is something that can be either a type object or an object instance. To allow the compiler to rely on this simple either/or boolean at compile time, the behavior of "definiteness", and thus the `.DEFINITE` macro, cannot be overridden by user code -- unlike the `.defined` method.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible add a *definiteness* constraint on parameterized roles using `R:D[Str]` syntax.

So, your example would look like this:

```raku
role R[::T] { }
class S does R[Str] { }
my R:D[Str] $r = S.new;
```

However keep in mind that `$r` could be *definite* yet *undefined* (see @raiph's answer):

```raku
role R[::T] { method defined { False} }
  class S does R[Str] { }
  my R:D[Str] $r = S.new; 
  say $r // 'undefined';
```

Comment: Hi @wamba. Another perfect answer, nailing the succinct solution. ✅ But I want to draw attention to an error in your answer (and the question and some of the doc). The `:D` constraint is a *definiteness* constraint, not a *definedness* constraint. cf `-> Mu:D $_ { say "DEFINITE={.DEFINITE} defined={.defined}" }(Failure.new)# DEFINITE=True defined=False`. For further discussion, see my answer.

Comment: Hi @raiph, thank you for your explanation. Maybe this part https://docs.raku.org/language/containers.html#Definedness_constraints of the documentation needs some revision.